# Stripe: The subscription schedule update is missing at least one phase with a `start_date` to anchor end dates to

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a subscription schedule from existing subscription using Stripe API.
My current steps are:

1. Create subscription
2. Create subscription schedule from subscription above
3. Update subscription schedule with new phases

But what I get is an error from the title:

```
The subscription schedule update is missing at least one phase with a `start_date` to anchor end dates to
```

Problem is that my code actually does have `start_date` in the phases:

```
const subscriptionSchedule = await this.stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
  from_subscription: subscription.id
});

return await this.stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(subscriptionSchedule.id, {
  end_behavior: "release",
  phases:[
    {
      end_date: canceledSubscription.current_period_end,
      items: [{
        price: plan
      }]
    },
    {
      start_date: canceledSubscription.current_period_end,
      items: [{
        price: plan
      }]
    }
  ]
});
```

So `subscription` is newly created subscription, and `canceledSubscription` is the subscription that got canceled in order for new subscription to take effect. And the point of whole logic is for new subscription to start once old one has ended.

So any ideas here would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing a `start_date` in the first phase.

Example

```
const subscriptionSchedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update(
        'sub_...', {
          end_behavior: "release",
          phases:[
            {
              start_date : 1662427226,
              end_date: 1664583692,
              items: [{
                price: 'price_...'
              }]
            },
            {
              start_date: 1664583692,
              items: [{
                price: 'price_...'
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
        );
```